# constructing a perpendicular triangle from 2 given points

Tags: matlab

I want to construct a perpendicular triangle from two given points `A` and `B`. In this particular case the line `c` created from these points is ascending into `y`direction for each `x`. (pink colors)

At the point `B` I want to construct the leg `a` with a fixed length in a 90° angle with a downward direction. (color green).

From the above follows the point `C` and segment `b` (purple).

[image]

I have written the following Matlab code to calc `C` and display the result.

```
A = [ 1 1 ];
B = [ 5 4 ];

a = 2; % fixed len

c = sqrt((B(1)-A(1))^2 + (B(2)-A(2))^2);
b = sqrt(c^2 + a^2);

alpha = atan(a/c);
gamma = atan(c/a);

C = A + 1/tan(gamma)*[-1 * (B(2)-A(2)) (B(1)-A(1))];

ALL = [A;B;C]

x = ALL(:,1);
y = ALL(:,2);

%plot
xlim([-2 8]);
ylim([-2 8]);
patch(x,y, 'green');

% debug output
acheck = sqrt((A(1)-C(1))^2 + (A(2)-C(2))^2) % this should be B-C but somehow it isnt
alpha_deg = rad2deg(alpha);
gamma_deg = rad2deg(gamma);
```

And this is the result of the plotting.

[image]

As you can see the leg `a` has been constructed at point `A` and not at point `B` and the leg is pointing into the opposite direction that I want it to.

I'd be grateful if someone could explain the errors of my way.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you explain your rationale behind the line `C = A + 1/tan(gamma)*[-1 * (B(2)-A(2)) (B(1)-A(1))];`

Comment: i copied that from another SO answer on how to calc a missing Point C

Comment: then you need to edit your question to link to that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you find from `1/tan(gamma)*[-1 * (B(2)-A(2)) (B(1)-A(1))]` is the vector pointing from B to C. Add B to it.

Answer (score 1):

wouldn't it be easier to just calculate a orthonormal vector to B-A?
something like:

```
n = [A(2)-B(2) B(1)-A(1)];
n = n/norm(n)*2;
C = B+n;
```

or

```
C = B-n;
```